# Problema insert into para agregar datos a diferentes tablas

Tags: php, mysqldb

tengo un formulario con diferentes inputs, los cuales son primero datos personales, otro bloque con telefono, otro con mail y por ultimo direccion.
esto se deriva al codigo que copio mas abajo, y lo que pretendo es que lo inserte en 3 tablas diferentes, una de datos personales, otra de telefonos, otra de mail y por ultimo otra de direcciones.

```php
    if(isset($_POST['alta_persona_fisica'])){
        $campos=array(); 
        foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
        {
            if($k != "generar_recibo"){
                if ($v !=""){
                    $campos[]="$k='$v'";
                }    
            }
        }
        
        include 'abrir_conexion.php';
        $consulta = $conexion -> query ("INSERT INTO alta_cliente SET ".implode(", ", $campos)) or die ("Ha fallado la conexión 11");

        $consulta = $conexion -> query ("INSERT INTO telefonos SET ".implode(", ", $campos)) or die ("Ha fallado la conexión 11");

        $consulta = $conexion -> query ("INSERT INTO email SET ".implode(", ", $campos)) or die ("Ha fallado la conexión 11");      

    }
```

al ejecutar el codigo me arroja el error, dado que las tablas no tienen los mismos datos.. osea de los datos que vienen por post solo tienen que copiarse a la tabla alta de clientes el nombre y apellido, id del cliente, y la edad, a la tabla de telefono solo el id del cliente y el telefono, a la de direccion solo el id del cliente y la direccion, y a la de emial idem

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que arroja y qué depuración has hecho de tus datos? Si no has depurado nada, pon un `var_dump($_POST);` en tu código y dinos qué muestra. Hay que ver de qué forma vienen los datos diferenciados en el `$_POST` para poder construir cada consulta diferenciando cada dato, no puedes generalizarlo todo en tu array `$campos`, de hecho, ese bucle es inútil para lo que quieres lograr.